# Is there a simple way to roll back the .Net version of a project in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I built a project in visual studio with the .Net framework v4.8, but the computers that this will run on are an older .net version. Is there a simple way to change this in visual studio without starting a new solution and copying all the code over?

Comment: Have you tried changing it (`Project > Properties > Application tab > Target framework`)  and checking if you get any errors?

Comment: That did it for the most part. I had some NuGet packages as well that I had to uninstall and reinstall after changing the target framework the way you suggested. Thanks!